# Adding scatter animations across frames in plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly, plotly-express

I want to add scatter points over an animation i am doing w/ px.imshow:

```
# video is a [n_frames, height, width, 3] array
fig = px.imshow(video, animation_frame=0, binary_string=True, height=height)
for i in range(video .shape[0]):
    str_plot = go.Scatter(x=[kp1[0, i], kp2[0, i]], y=[kp1[1, i], kp2[1, i]], mode='markers+lines',
            marker=dict(color='red', size=5), xaxis='x', yaxis='y')
    fig['frames'][i]['data'] = list(fig['frames'][i]['data']) + [str_plot]
```

This kinda works, where i can see both scatter and img when i move the slider, but not when it plays by itself. I assume there is a better way to do this. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: I experimented with mimicking your code based on this example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#exploring-3d-images-and-timeseries-with-animationframe). I was able to animate, but the image frames and scatter plots did not work together. This is because the image frame is a `base64` string and the scatter plot is scatter data with a numeric axis. You cannot put these in one frame.

Comment: What happens if you first create all individual composite frames according to https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#combining-image-charts-and-other-traces . Save each generated plot as an image (fig.to_image), and then plot them again, but this time using px and animate?